# Display web page preview with FAST Search for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, fast-search

We have a enterprise farm installation of SP2010 and have configured FAST search for SharePoint. We have also enable office web apps for thumbnail and document preview. All setup is running fine.

However I would like to modify the search results to display a preview of the web page similar to what we can see when we do Google search. Can this be possible OOTB with some customization's to the search results web part? Any pointers to any blogs / articles would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party product from Ontolica which is somewhat close to your requirement. Visit [this link](http://www.surfray.com/product/ontolica-search-preview) to download a trial and check it out.

Good Luck ...

Comment: Seems interesting, but i think I might not be able to invest in a third party product for now. Do we have any such functionality provided OOTB from SharePoint with some customizations with jQuery or so?